# Template Hierarchy tag-{slug}.php directory

Tags: directory, template-hierarchy

When `tag-{slug}.php` is in the root of theme, say `wp-content/themes/p2/tag-{slug}.php`, the template hierarchy is respected.

However, I have many such custom files and just cannot have it in the theme root directory  . When I tested with `p2/tag` and `p2/custom-tag` directories, it did not work.

Any insight?

Comment: Without knowing exactly why you have many, or other details, one suggestion would be to look into using template parts.  This would allow you to use one tag template file with some logic around various `get_template_part` statements: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part.  Your many parts could reside in a folder that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at the source code, the tag template is loaded as follow in template hierarchy

- `elseif ( is_tag() && $template = get_tag_template() ) :` in [`wp-includes/template-loader.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/template-loader.php#L0)
- [`get_tag_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_tag_template/) uses [`get_query_template()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_template) which uses [`locate_template()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template)
- which loads the tag template according to hierarchy from the theme root folder

So, moving your templates to a sub-folder will not work out-of-the-box. `get_query_template()` however have a filter (*`apply_filters( "{$type}_template", $template )`*) that we can use to change this behavior and load our `tag-{$tag->slug}.php` from a subfolder

So, we should do the following

- Check if our `tag-{$tag->slug}.php` exists in our subfolder of choice
- Load our `tag-{$tag->slug}.php` from subfolder if it exists
- Load default templates from the hierarchy if `tag-{$tag->slug}.php` does not exists in a subfolder

Something like the following will work

```
add_filter( 'tag_template', function ( $template )
{
    $tag = get_queried_object();
    // Alternative path to desired template
    $alternative_template = locate_template( "custom-sub-folder/tag-{$tag->slug}.php" ); // Change subfolder name

    // If we do have "tag-{$tag->slug}.php" in a subfolder, load "subfolder/tag-{$tag->slug}.php"
    if (  $alternative_template )
        return $template = $alternative_template;

    // If we don't have a "tag-{$tag->slug}.php", load templates according to hierarchy
    return $template;
});
```